# Auto Inventory Program - Problems with file output and capturing int Index

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AutoMobile {

    private static String make;
    private static String model;
    private static String color;
    private static int year;
    private static int mileage;
    private static int index =300;


    public AutoMobile(String make, String model, String color, int year,
                      int mileage, int index) {
        super();
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.year = year;
        this.mileage = mileage;
        this.index = index;
    }



    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }

    public void setMileage(int mileage) {
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }

    public static int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

}

class Vehicle {
    static ArrayList<AutoMobile> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String FILENAME = "F:\\CSU\\CSC320-01 Programming 1\\Week 8\\AutoMobile.txt";
    //Prints to location with proper header, but returns package and no vehicles

    public static  void addVehicle() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("------Add Vehicle-------");
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle make: ");
        String make = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle model: ");
        String model = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle color: ");
        String color = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle year: ");
        int year = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle mileage: ");
        int mileage = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        int index = s.nextInt();
        AutoMobile a = new AutoMobile(make, model, color, year, mileage, index);
        vehicleList.add(a);
        System.out.println("Vehicle Added Successfully");
        System.out.println("------------------------");

    }

    public static void removeVehicle() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("------Remove Vehicle-------");
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle make: ");
        String make = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle model: ");
        String model = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        int index = s.nextInt();
        ListIterator<AutoMobile> iterator =vehicleList.listIterator();
        boolean find = false;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            AutoMobile a1 =iterator.next();
            if(a1.getMake().equalsIgnoreCase(make) && a1.getModel().equalsIgnoreCase(model) &&
                    a1.getIndex().equalsIgnoreCase(index)){ // Line Showing Error
                iterator.remove();
                find = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(find){
            System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No such Vehicle Exist");
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        }

    }

    public static void updateVehicle() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("------Update Vehicle-------");
        System.out.print("Enter the make of Automobile: ");
        String make = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the model of Automobile: ");
        String model = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        int index = s.nextInt();
        ListIterator<AutoMobile> iterator =vehicleList.listIterator();
        boolean find = false;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            AutoMobile a1 =iterator.next();
            if(a1.getMake().equalsIgnoreCase(make) && a1.getModel().equalsIgnoreCase(model)
            && a1.getIndex().equalsIgnoreCase(index)){ // Line Showing Error
                System.out.println("-----Vehicle found-------");
                System.out.print("Enter the new make of Automobile: ");
                make = s.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the new model of Automobile: ");
                model = s.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the new color of Automobile: ");
                String color = s.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the new year of Automobile: ");
                int year = s.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter the new mileage of Automobile: ");
                int mileage = s.nextInt();
                a1.setMake(make);
                a1.setModel(model);
                a1.setColor(color);
                a1.setYear(year);
                a1.setMileage(mileage);
                a1.setIndex(index);
                find = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(find){
            System.out.println("Vehicle Updated Successfully");
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No such Vehicle Exist");
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        }
    }

    public static void printfile() {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {

            fw = new FileWriter(FILENAME);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String content = "ID Make Model Color Year Mileage\n";
            bw.write(content);
            Iterator itr=vehicleList.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                bw.write(itr.next().toString()+"\n");
            }
            System.out.println("Done printing");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();
                if (fw != null)
                    fw.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        do {

            System.out
                    .println("============================VEHICLE OPTIONS============================");
            System.out.println("1. Add Vehicle");
            System.out.println("2. Remove Vehicle");
            System.out.println("3. Update Vehicle");
            System.out.println("4. Print Vehicle List");
            System.out.println("5. Exit");
            System.out
                    .println("=======================================================================");
            System.out.println();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the choice: ");
            int i = s.nextInt();
            s.nextLine();
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    addVehicle();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    removeVehicle();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    updateVehicle();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printfile();
                    break;
                case 5:
                System.out.println("Good Bye!!!!!");
                break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You  entered the wrong choice!!!!");
                    System.out.println();
            }
            if(i==4)
                break;
            System.out.println();
        } while (true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("VehicleInventory");
        String text ="Index,Make,Model,Color,Year,Mileage\n";
        for(AutoMobile a : vehicleList){
            text+=a.getIndex()+","+a.getMake()+","+a.getModel()+","+a.getColor()+","+a.getYear()+","+a.getMileage()+"\n";
        }
        pw.write(text);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("VehicleInventory file created succesfully");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(text);


    }

}
```

Forgive my inexperience, but I am trying to compile a program for school that achieves the following.

```
private string make
private string model
private string color
private int year
private int mileage.
```

Your program should have appropriate methods such as:

```
default constructor
parameterized constructor
add a new vehicle  method
list vehicle information (return string array)
remove a vehicle method
update vehicle attributes method.
```

All methods should include `try..catch` constructs. Except as noted all methods should return a success or failure message (failure message defined in `catch`).

1. Create an additional class to call your automobile class (e.g., Main or AutomobileInventory). Include a try..catch construct and print it to the console any errors.
2. Call automobile class with parameterized constructor (e.g., "`make, model, color, year, mileage`").

   1. Then call the method to list the values. Loop through the array and print to the screen.
3. Call the remove vehicle method to clear the variables.

   1. Print the return value.
4. Add a new vehicle.

   1. Print the return value.
   2. Call the list method and print the new vehicle information to the screen.
5. Update the vehicle.

   1. Print the return value.
   2. Call the listing method and print the information to the screen.
6. Display a message asking if the user wants to print the information to a file (Y or N).

   1. Use a scanner to capture the response. If `Y`, print the file to a predefined location (e.g., `C:\Temp\Autos.txt`). Note: you may want to create a method to print the information in the main class.
   2. If `N`, indicate that a file will not be printed.

I have the program working somewhat as i wanted, until i tried to assign index numbers to the user inputted vehicles for updating or removing at a later date.  This does not return in the output, and all that is returning in the .txt file is the header, and my package listed, no vehicles.  Any suggestions or help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Some of the details in your question doesn't seem relavent to the problem you are having. Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: As for the problem you are having, before writing the result to file, write those results to the console to make sure what you are trying to write to the file is actually being written.

Comment: Sorry I am going crosseyed working through this.  Jagadesh's suggestion was one that I was looking for, I had inadevertantly overlooked this.  My output for the program as well as the other functionality is working now, the only thing I am struggling with is linking the program to the output .txt file, in which actually generates my list.

Answer (score 0):

`index` parameter is of primitive `int` data type

For `int` use `=` for comparing.

```
if (a1.getMake().equalsIgnoreCase(make) && a1.getModel().equalsIgnoreCase(model)
                    && a1.getIndex() == index) {}
```